# PHP Ajax Call - JavaScript won't work after call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm all new to this but I hope you can help me and explain the cause of it.

I have an application where I make an AJAX call to a site which generates Tables based on an SQL Query. Everything worked fine but now I tried to make the table sortable. I downloaded a JavaScript file and without the AJAX call everything works as it should. But when I call the site via AJAX then the sortable function won't work.

Here is a simplify version of it the Ajax call:

**test.php
**

```
<head>

 <script src="/js/sorttable.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>
<div class="container" >    
    <div id="box"> </div>
</div>

</body>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
    loadStatus();
}

// LOAD Statusmonitor
const interval = setInterval(function() {
    loadStatus() }, 3000);

function loadStatus(){

    //XHR Objekt
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // OPEN
    xhr.open('GET', 'ajax/call.php', true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(this.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = this.responseText;         
     var newTableObject = document.getElementById('statustable')
                    sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);   
        }
        if(this.status == 404){
            document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = 'ERROR';
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
</script>
```

**ajax/Call.php
**

```
<h2 class="text-center mt-5">Statusmonitor TESTSITE</h2>
<h5 class="text-muted text-center mb-3"><?php echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s');?>
</h5>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Ei</th>
      <th scope="col">T</th>
      <th scope="col">num</th>
      <th scope="col">Ort</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Min:Sek</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
        <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried as you see to include the js file even in the call.php and if I load this site directly everything works. But as soon as the ajax Function calls my site the JavaScript seems not to work.

I would really appreciate if someone could help and explain the problem to me.

Please forgive me if my question is not formulated perfectly or my knowledge is very basic

Thanks

I want an sortable Table with an ajax call

*** UPDATE ***

I managed thanks to the input to make it sortable by calling the table again. I looked in to the Documentation of the JS: https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

But now I have the problem that when the ajax refresh the site (every 3 seconds) it unsort the table again. Is there an way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I will have to make some assumptions. It goes like this: The first time the JS code inside `/js/sorttable.js` is executed it scans for HTML tables with the class `sortable`, and it sorts them. Your AJAX call now changes the HTML, but the JS code inside `/js/sorttable.js` is not executed again. Therefore the table is not sorted. What you need to do, after you changed the HTML, is call something in the `/js/sorttable.js` to force it to sort your table. I can't really answer your question, because of all the assumptions I have to make, since I don't know the content `/js/sorttable.js`.

Comment: Thanks to your input, i have looked in the documentation of the JS File . and i found a Solution,  by adding  var newTableObject = document.getElementById('statustable')
                    sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject); - BUT when the ajax call make an request it unsort the table again , is there a way to prevent this from happening

Comment: Well after you makeSortable. find the command to sortOnASpecificColumn again in the javascript library